# Control popup modal with cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to control the behavior of a popup modal with cookies.  Ideally the functionality would be as follows:
The modal pops up about 3 seconds after the page is loaded.  The if the user closes out of the popup modal, a cookie is created with a max age of 2 days (I'm using 30 second increments for testing purposes).  The logic is that if the cookie does not exist, i.e. when it expires, a class of 'show' will be added to the modal making it appear again.  First of all, I can't get that to work at all.  The second problem is getting the modal to appear in the first place.  My initial idea was to set a timer, but then it would keep appearing every time the user navigates or refreshes.  Then I tried adding a cookie to initially set the class using the event listener "DOMConentLoaded", but that gives me the same problem.  I'm brand new to cookies and learning how they can used.  Any ideas?  Thanks so much in advance!

```html
<div id="popup" class="popup grid u-bgColorPrimary">
    <div class="grid__col--7">
        <h1>New Popup</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
        <div id="close" class="popup__close"></div>
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/images/careers-bg.png'; ?>" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
let popup = document.getElementById("popup");
let close = document.getElementById("close");

// Timer for Popup modal
// setTimeout(() => {
//   popup.classList.add("popup--show");
// }, 3000);

close.addEventListener("click", () => {
  popup.classList.remove("popup--show");
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let key = "initiate_cookie";
  let value = encodeURIComponent("show_popup");
  let age = 15;
  let cookie = document.cookie = `${key}=${value};path=/;max-age=${age};`

  if (cookie) {
    popup.classList.add("popup--show");
  } else {
    popup.classList.remove("popup--show")
  }
});

document.getElementById("close").addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  let key = "popup_display";
  let value = encodeURIComponent("show");
  let age = 30;

  document.cookie = `${key}=${value};path=/;max-age=${age};`;
  let cookie = document.cookie = `${key}=${value};path=/;max-age=${age};`


  if (!cookie) {
    popup.classList.add("popup--show");
  } else {
    popup.classList.remove("popup--show");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before deciding to if you should show your popup, first get the cookie. The timer is a good idea, but you'll need to know if you need to start the timer.

Check if the cookie exists. If the cookie has not been set, then run the timer and show the popup. Whenever the popup gets closed, set the cookie.

The next time the page loads it will evaluate again if the cookie has been set, but now it should be set and therefor the timer will not run and the popup not show.

Whenever the cookie is expired and the page is loaded again, the popup will be shown again.

The example below demonstrates this behavior.

```
// Returns the cookie value or null.
const getCookie = name => {
  const nameExpression = `${name}=`;
  const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
  const cookie = cookies.find(currentCookie => currentCookie.includes(nameExpression));  
  return cookie ? cookie.trim().substring(nameExpression.length, cookie.length) : null;
}

// Sets the cookie.
const setCookie = (name, value, expire = 365, path = '/') => {
  const date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (expire * 24 * 3600 * 1000));
  const expires = date.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = `${name}=${value}; expires=${expires}; path=${path}`;
};

const popup = document.getElementById("popup");
const close = document.getElementById("close");

// Define the name of the cookie.
cookieName = "popup-display";

// First get the cookie..
const cookie = getCookie(cookieName);

// ..then check if the cookie is not set.
if (cookie !== 'show') {

  // If it isn't set, show the popup after 3 seconds..
  setTimeout(() => {
    popup.classList.add("popup--show");
  }, 3000);

  // ..and add the event listener.
  close.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    
    // Set the cookie with the value show for 2 days..
    setCookie(cookieName, "show", 2);

    // ..and hide the popup
    popup.classList.remove("popup--show");
  });
}
```

The current `setCookie` function sets the time in days. To help debug use the function below which sets the time in seconds.

```
const setShortCookie = (name, value, seconds, path = '/') => {
  const date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (seconds * 1000));
  const expires = date.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = `${name}=${value}; expires=${expires}; path=${path}`;
};
```

Comment: I think I follow what's going on here.  However, after implementing this code, the modal popup still appears when navigating to a different page or refreshing the page after closing it.

Comment: Actually I think I might have figured out what was wrong.  It looks like nameExpression.length needed a +1 to just get 'show' (otherwise the value was being read as '=show'.  It appears to be working now, however I guess I won't know for a couple days!  Is it possible to set the expire argument to anything less than days to test it out?

Comment: You're right. It seems that strings needed to be trimmed beforehand so that the length was correct. To help you debug, I've added a variant of the `setCookie` function which sets the cookie expiration date in seconds.